# How to display letters on new line in css

Tags: html, css

I have four divs which shows a number, I want to display the words below those numbers. I have tried using the `p` tag with `white-space: pre;` in css, but still it does not work:

```css
#c {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.cnum {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
  <span class='cnum'>27 Text1</span><span class='cnum'>10 Text2</span><span class='cnum'>40 Text 3</span><span class='cnum'>5 Text 4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Am image of the desired result woudl be useful

Comment: you can't change the HTML, i.e. insert a `<br>` tag?

Comment: ..or just break the span into two elements..and style accordingly.

Comment: and what's the CSS for `p` about - there is no `<p>` tag in your HTML?

Comment: So the short answer is: it's not possible via CSS only, you'll have to modify your HTML. By hand or via JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="c">
   <div class='cnum'>27 <br/>Text1</div>
   <div class='cnum'>10 <br/>Text2</div>
   <div class='cnum'>40 <br/>Text 3</div>
   <div class='cnum'>5 <br/>Text 4</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#c{
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
.cnum{
    background: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    margin:5px;
    font-size:20px;
    max-Width :100px;
    float :left
 }
```

[Heres a CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKYZeB)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't edit the HTML, here's a workaround using `word-spacing`. Obviously this method is *very* limited...

```css
#c {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.cnum {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  word-spacing: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
  <span class='cnum'>27 Text1</span><span class='cnum'>10 Text2</span><span class='cnum'>40 Text3</span><span class='cnum'>5 Text4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just separated the elements according to the hierarchy so that I could then apply the style. If you observe keep the span tags, but you could replace them with a block element.

I recommend you to learn about inline and block HTML elements and how to convert them in each other.

I hope I have contributed.

```css
#c {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.cnum {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.cnum span{
  display: block;
}

p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
  <div class="cnum">
    <span>27</span>
    <span>Text 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cnum">
    <span>10</span>
    <span>Text 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cnum">
    <span>40</span>
    <span>Text 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cnum">
    <span>5</span>
    <span>Text 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the html you can do the following, additionally using the pseudo selector `::first-line` style the numbers differently

```css
#c {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.cnum {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.cnum::first-line {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="c">
   <div class='cnum'>27 <br/>Text1</div>
   <div class='cnum'>10 <br/>Text2</div>
   <div class='cnum'>40 <br/>Text 3</div>
   <div class='cnum'>5 <br/>Text 4</div>
 </div>
```